# Text to HTML in PHP

Tags: php, html, text, formatting, text-to-html

nl2br(); can do for EOL but what about white spaces and/or tabs at the beginning(or not) of line? Is there any function to do this at once? I need well formatted html output of text file.
Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well may be `<pre>....</pre>` can do it

also see

```
htmlspecialchars()
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

```
htmlentities()
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: Thx. How to mark it as done? You are very useful. Greetings.
//EDIT: Ok. I can do it after some time.. 2 min. left..

Answer (score 0):

It is OK to use "pre" HTML tag.

```
<?php
echo '<pre>' ;
/// .... do text output stuff...
echo '</pre>' ;
?>
```

Sorry for my lame question. I'm new in WoW(word of web).